# Behaviour of the sequence $u_n = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, math-software

Let  $n\in \mathbb{N}^{*}$, let  ${\displaystyle u_{n}={2n \choose n}\sqrt{n}\ 4^{-n}}$

Show that  $(u_{n})_{n}$ is convergent and ${l.e^{-\frac{1}{8n}}<u_{n}<l}$

The original text

[image]

i'm trying to compute $\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$ but i failed 
even with wolframe

```
{u(n) = (binomial(2 n, n) sqrt(n))×4^(-n), (u(n+1))/(u(n))=? }
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Isn't that something like $\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n} }}{4(n+1)^2}$?

Comment: you want to say ${(2n+2) \choose (2n+1)}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}{4(n+1)^2}$

Comment: No I want to say what I wrote. Using ${{2n}\choose{n}} =\frac{(2n)!}{n!^2}$.

Comment: @servabat may be you're right

Comment: $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = \frac{(2(n+1) )!\sqrt{n+1}}{(n+1)!^2 4^{n+1}} \times \frac{ (n)!^2 4^{n}} { (2n)!\sqrt{n} } $ ?

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$ u_n = \sqrt{n}\frac{(2n)!}{4^n n!^2} = \sqrt{n}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = \sqrt{n}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right),$$
so:
$$ u_n^2 = \frac{n}{4}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{4k^2}\right)=\frac{n}{4}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right) $$
or just :
$$ u_n^2 = \frac{1}{4}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right). $$
Since the product, as $n\to +\infty$, is convergent, we have:
$$ u_n^2 \leq \frac{1}{4}\prod_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k+1)}\right)=C.$$
On the other hand:
$$ u_n^2 = \frac{C}{\prod_{k=n}^{+\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k+1)}\right)}\geq\frac{C}{\exp\left(\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=n}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\right)}=C e^{-\frac{1}{4n}}. $$

Comment: what does !! means and how did you get $u_n = \sqrt{n}\frac{(2n)!}{4^n n!^2} = \sqrt{n}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} = \sqrt{n}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right),$  could you please elaborate

Comment: $$(2n)!!=(2n)(2n-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot 2$$ and $$(2n-1)!!=(2n-1)(2n-3)\cdot\ldots\cdot 1.$$

Comment: could you add another way please

Comment: @Educ: I do not have another way.

Comment: if we have that $u_n^2 \geq C e^{-\frac{1}{4n}}$ what does mean please add more detaile to see why you prove this $u_n^2 \geq C e^{-\frac{1}{4n}}$  and how we can ${l.e^{-\frac{1}{8n}}<u_{n}<l}$

Comment: @Educ: just take the square root. $l=\sqrt{C}$.

Comment: @Educ: are you kidding me? The square root of $C e^{-\frac{1}{4n}}$ is $l e^{-\frac{1}{8n}}$ that is *exactly* what you need. How about studying basic calculus a little more before approaching this kind of subtle exercises?

Comment: if you just could tell me the principale of what you did . you show that ^$(u_n)^2$ is convergent is that so we can say $u_n$ is convergent too, thanks for ur time

Comment: @Educ: sorry for being a bit harsh before. Yes, since $u_n^2$ is between $C e^{-\frac{1}{4n}}$ and $C$ and $u_n>0$, by taking the square root we have that $u_n$ is between $l\,e^{-\frac{1}{8n}}$ and $l$ as wanted.

Comment: how could you prove that $u_n^2$ is increasing

Comment: @Educ: that is really trivial. For any $n\geq 2$, $$\frac{u_{n+1}^2}{u_n^2}=1+\frac{1}{4n(n+1)}>1.$$