# study series based on geometric series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let ${\displaystyle S_{n}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{3^k}}$ and ${\displaystyle S'_{n}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{k}{3^k}}$
>
> - Show that  $(S_{n})_{n}$ is convergent and calculate its limit
> - Study $(S'_n)_{n}$

The original of text
[image]

for $S_n$ is  Geometric series then $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{3^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{k}=\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{0}\times \dfrac{1-\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)}=\dfrac{3}{2}( 1-\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{n+1} )$

when $n\to +\infty\quad S_n \to \dfrac{3}{2}$

for second question here is another way:

\begin{align*}
S'_n+S_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k+1}{3^k}\\
S'_n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k+1}{3^k}-S_n\\
S'_n&=3\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{k+1}{3^{k+1}}- S_n\\
&=3\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{k}{3^{k}}- S_n\\
&=3S'_n+\frac{n+1}{3^n}-S_n
\end{align*}

(note that $S'_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{k}{3^k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac {k}{3^k})$

$$S'_n=\frac{1}{2} ( S_n-\frac{n+1}{3^n})$$
Thus  $S'_n$ is converge to $\dfrac{3}{4}$

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct for the first series. For the second let

$$u(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac1{1-x},\quad |x|<1$$
then

$$u'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty k x^{k-1}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}$$
so for $x=\frac13$ we get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}S'_n=\frac{\frac13}{(1-\frac13)^2}=\frac34$$

Comment: but $S'_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{k}{3^k}$ not $S'_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\dfrac{k}{3^{k-1}}$

Comment: I multiplied $u'(x)$ by $x$.

Comment: yep i see but this way is just like you know already the answer is there another way analytic to start from $S'_n$ if we want to explain someone how t study that series

Comment: i upvote ur question, could you see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066901/behaviour-of-the-sequence-u-n-frac-sqrtn4n-binom2nn

Comment: In the given answer Jack used the [double factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Comment: i don't know this notion could you propose another way please

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{k}{3^k} = k\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^k$, and

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n kx^k = x\left(1+x+x^2+\cdots x^n\right)'$

Comment: how did you get $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n kx^k = x\left(1+x+x^2+\cdots x^n\right)'$ can you elaborate this

Comment: If you take derivative term by term and times the result by $x$ to see what you get?