# solution verification

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, problem-solving, solution-verification

here is solution of my old question but i can't see it would someone explain to me the principal idea and what he wants to show

[Solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066901/behaviour-of-the-sequence-u-n-frac-sqrtn4n-binom2nn/1066929?noredirect=1#comment2196296_1066929)

from $u_n=\sqrt{n}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right),$ To $u^2_n=\frac{n}{4}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{4k^2}\right),$

and from
$u^2_n= \frac{n}{4}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{4k^2}\right)$
To $u^2_n=\frac{n}{4}\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\prod_{k=2}^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right)$

and if we've that $u_n^2$ convergent is that means $u_n$ also convergent

i just need to see the principal idea  of what he did Thanks

I think the principal idea of solution is that he want to show $u_n^2$ convergent and bounded then tell that $u_n$ is convergent too
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you tell us what *principale* is and what you have tried yourself, maybe someone can help.

Comment: I think the principal idea of solution is that he want to show $u_n^2$ convergent and bounded then tell that $u_n$ is convergent too

Answer (score 1):

Note first that
$$
1-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{4k^2}
=\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\left(1+\frac{k}{k-1}\cdot\frac{1}{4k^2}\right)=
\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{4(k-1)k}\right).
$$
Next,
$$
\frac{n}{4}\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)=\frac{n}{4}\prod_{k=2}^n
\frac{k-1}{k}=\frac{1}{4}.
$$
Then
$$
\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right)=\exp\left(\sum_{k=2}^n
\log\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right)\right)\le\exp\left(\sum_{k=2}^n
\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right), 
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n
\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)=1-\frac{1}{n}<1.
$$
Thus
$$
\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right)\le \exp\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)
$$
and hence $\{u_n^2\}$ is upper bounded and increasing, and thus convergent, and so is $\{u_n\}$, as $u_n>0$.

Comment: is it $u_n^2=\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right)$ could you just add little details please

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: how can you proof that $u_n^2$ is increasing ??

Comment: but you said that $\{u_n^2\}$ is upper bounded and increasing

Comment: I have deleted my previous comment, because it was wrong. Indeed $\{u_n^2\}$ is increasing since $$u_n^2=\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right).$$ Observe that $\,\frac{u^2_{n+1}}{u_n^2}=1+\frac{1}{4n(n+1)}>1$.

Comment: check this also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095746/u-n2-is-increasing/1095837#1095837