# $\{u_n^2\}$ is increasing

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

> how he does Know that  $\{u_n^2\}$ is increasing this question is related to that one [solution verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079614/solution-verification?lq=1)

here is his solution

Note first that
$$
1-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{4k^2}
=\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\left(1+\frac{k}{k-1}\cdot\frac{1}{4k^2}\right)=
\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{4(k-1)k}\right).
$$
Next,
$$
\frac{n}{4}\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)=\frac{n}{4}\prod_{k=2}^n
\frac{k-1}{k}=\frac{1}{4}.
$$
Then
$$
\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right)=\exp\left(\sum_{k=2}^n
\log\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right)\right)\le\exp\left(\sum_{k=2}^n
\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right), 
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n
\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\sum_{k=2}^n\left(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k}\right)=1-\frac{1}{n}<1.
$$
Thus
$$
\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{4k(k-1)}\right)\le \exp\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)
$$
and hence $\{u_n^2\}$ is upper bounded and increasing, and thus convergent, and so is $\{u_n\}$, as $u_n>0$.

Comment: Just because the product of terms of the form $(1+a_n)$ is increasing if $a_n$ is positive

Answer (score 0):

$$b_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n} (1+a_k)>1$$

Assume each $a_k$ to be positive.

$$b_{n+1}=\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} (1+a_k)=b_n(1+a_{n+1})>b_n$$