# $\frac{(2n)!}{4^n n!^2} = \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\bigl(1-\frac{1}{2k}\bigr)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

> i cant see why we have :
>
> - $$\frac{(2n)!}{4^n n!^2} = \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$$
> - $$\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} =\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2k}\right),$$

Even i see the notion of [Double factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial)

this question is related to that one : [Behaviour of the sequence $u_n = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066901/behaviour-of-the-sequence-u-n-frac-sqrtn4n-binom2nn)

- For  $\frac{(2n)!}{4^n n!^2} = \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$

$\dfrac{(2n)!}{4^n n!^2}=\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} n!^2}=\dfrac{(2n)\times (2n-1)!}{2^{2n} (n\times (n-2)!)^2}$

- For  $\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!} =\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2k}\right),$

note that $n!! = \prod_{i=0}^k (n-2i) = n (n-2) (n-4) \cdots$

$\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}=\dfrac{\prod_{i=0}^k (2n-1-2i)}{\prod_{i=0}^k (2n-2i)}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note first that $(2n)!=(2n)!!(2n-1)!!$, because $(2n)!!$ gives you the even factors in $(2n)!$, and $(2n-1)!!$ gives you the odd factors. Now

$$\begin{align*}
(2n)!!&=(2n)(2n-2)(2n-4)\ldots(4)(2)\\
&=\big(2n\big)\big(2(n-1)\big)\big(2(n-2)\big)\ldots\big(2(2)\big)\big(2(1)\big)\\
&=2^nn!\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\frac{(2n)!}{4^nn!^2}=\frac{(2n)!!(2n-1)!!}{2^{2n}n!^2}=\frac{2^nn!(2n-1)!!}{2^{2n}n!^2}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^nn!}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}\;.$$

Now

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}&=\frac{2n-1}{2n}\cdot\frac{2n-3}{2n-2}\cdot\frac{2n-5}{2n-4}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac34\cdot\frac12\\\\
&=\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)\left(1-\frac1{2n-2}\right)\left(1-\frac1{2n-4}\right)\ldots\left(1-\frac14\right)\left(1-\frac12\right)\\\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @BrianMScott Out of curiosity, is there a reason why you use `\ldots` rather than the conventional `\cdots` during multiplication constructions? I find that `\cdots` yields a more typographically pleasing output, but maybe you prefer the other construction.

Comment: @induktio: My æsthetics are the opposite of yours here (and it seems to me that both versions are standard/conventional). I dislike having the ellipsis run together with the operation.

Comment: @BrianMScott Interesting! I just came across the following in the TeXbook in the section about the fine points of mathematical typesetting: "In general, it is best to use `\cdots` between $+$ and $-$ and $\times$ signs, and also between $=$ signs or $\leq$ signs or $\subset$ signs or other similar relations. Low dots are used between commas, and when things are juxtaposed with no signs between them at all" (pg. 172). He gives this example: $(1-x)(1-x^2)\ldots (1-x^n)$. Neat. I guess everything I have read before has been typeset incorrectly.

Comment: @induktio: To be honest, I prefer (and use) the low dots in almost all settings. This may be because I’m older, and my æsthetics derive in large part from printed material that’s older than computer typesetting.

Comment: That's what we call detailed answer

Comment: could you explain to me why Jason wrote $2n!!=\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)$ i cant see from wiki $n!!=\prod_{i=0}^k (n-2i)$ so $2n!!=\prod_{k=1}^k(2n-2i)$

Comment: @Educ: That should be $(2n)!!=\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)$: the parentheses are crucial. $\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)$ and $\prod_{i=0}^{2n}(2n-2i)$ are the same products in reverse order: the first is $(2)(4)\ldots(2n-2)(2n)$, and the second is $(2n)(2n-2)\ldots(2)$.

Comment: in general we can right $n!!=\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)=\prod_{k=1}^n(n-k)$

Comment: @Educ: No: $\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)$ is $(2n)!!$, not $n!!$, and $\prod_{k=1}^n(n-k)=0$, since the last factor is $n-n=0$. What is true is that $$n!!=\prod_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(n-2k)\;.$$

Comment: and this is gonna be true only for $2n!!$ and $(2n-1)!!$

Comment: @Educ: I’m not sure what your *this* refers to. The displayed formula in my last comment is valid for all positive integers $n$.

Comment: i meant $(2n-1)!!=\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)$ and $(2n)!!=\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)$

Comment: @Educ: Ah, okay; then you’re absolutely right.

Comment: just to be sure have we : $(2n)!!=\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)=\prod_{i=0}^{2n}(2n-2i)$ and $(2n-1)!!=\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)=\prod_{i=0}^{2n-1}(2n-1-2i)$

Comment: @Educ: Not quite: the final product in the first case should be $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(2n-2i)$, so that the last factor is $2$, and the final product in the second case should be $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(2n-1-2i)$, so that the last factor is $1$.

Comment: there is typo at one of ur comments : Educ: That should be $(2n)!!=\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)$ : the parentheses are crucial.$\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)$ and $\prod_{i=0}^{2n}(2n-2i)$ here in that $\prod_{i=0}^{2n}(2n-2i)$ as you said should be $\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(2n-2i)$

Comment: @Educ: Good catch. Yes, that was a careless typo on my part.

Comment: i think ur definition of double factorial is not quite correct $n!!=\prod_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(n-2k)\;.$ the right one is $n!!=\prod_{k=0}^{k=\lceil n/2 \rceil - 1.}(n-2k)\;.$ with ceil function not with floor

Comment: @Educ: Oops. Yes, you’re right. What I wrote works fine for odd $n$ but gives $0$ when $n$ is even. And at this point I think that you can safely say that you’re on top of the subject! :-)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks you for ur time and ur detailed explantion :)

Comment: @Educ: You’re welcome. Sorry about the careless bits!

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{(2n)!}{4^nn!^2}=\dfrac{(2n)!!(2n-1)!!}{(2^nn!)^2}=\dfrac{(2n)!!(2n-1)!!}{((2n)!!)^2}=\dfrac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$

$\prod_{k=1}^n(1-\frac{1}{2k})=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{2k-1}{2k}=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)}{\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)}=\frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2n)!!}$

Comment: it's not detailed

Comment: from wiki $n!!=\prod_{i=0}^k (n-2i)$  so $2n!!=\prod_{k=1}^k(2n-2i)$ why we hace  $2n!!=\prod_{k=1}^n(2k)$

Comment: @Educ well, the product of $2n-2i$ where $i$ from $1$ to $n$ is equal to the product of $2k$ where $k$ from $1$ to $n$ (or $n$ to $1$), as long as you let $k=n-i$