# Is $x_1\cdot x_2\cdots x_n$ proper notation?

Tags: notation

In a textbook I recently saw the notation
$$x_1\cdot x_2\cdots x_n$$
which was intended to mean $\prod\limits_{i=1}^nx_i$.
This is unappealing to me because for example one wouldn't write
$$x_1+x_2\cdots x_n,$$
but rather
$$x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n.$$

On the other hand, there does not seem to be a good alternative since neither of the following look right -
$$x_1\cdot x_2\cdot\dots\cdot x_n$$
$$x_1\cdot x_2\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n$$

This leads to the question:

> Is $x_1\cdot x_2\cdots x_n$ the proper notation despite being inconsistent, or is there some other accepted way of using dots in conjunction with \cdot?

Comment: And why not just remove the first dot? That's how I'd solve the problem.

Comment: @SamuelYusim The textbook was introducing $x_1x_2\dots x_n$ as notation for the multiplication.

Comment: I would do as Samuel. Otherwise if one insist writing the product in between i would write $x_1 \times x_2  \times \cdots \times x_n$

Comment: I agree there are ways in this case to just avoid the notation, but I'm interested in knowing if there is a proper way to do it anyway.

Comment: I like @SamuelYusim's fix, that's what I would do. I'm generally very careful about where I put "\cdot" if there's an ellipsis in the equation. Individual \cdot's might also get confused with the dot product, so I make sure others know what it stands for. In the above notation I would have read it as product as it's not overly troublesome (and you seem to know exactly what they meant as well), but you could also write it as $x_1x_2\cdots x_n=\prod_{k=1}^nx_k$, which looks better, but in certain contexts I have seen the former might actually be better. So I think it all depends on where it is.

Comment: @MagicMan Sweet!

Comment: Why not use ldots: $x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot x_n$?

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret It could be that that is correct, but I don't know (I'm looking forward to seeing what Knuth has to say about it).

Comment: @Peter: I couldn’t care less what Knuth thinks: if one is going to write it with the explicit centre dots for multiplication, the only reasonable solution is $x_1\cdot x_2\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [$\mathrm{\TeX book}$](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201134470) (Chapter 18: Fine Points of Mathematics Typing, pg. 172):

> In general, it is best to use `\cdots` between $+$ and $-$ and $\times$ signs, and also between $=$ signs or $\leq$ signs or $\subset$ signs or other similar relations. Low dots are used between commas, and when things are juxtaposed with no signs between them at all.

For example:

- `$x_1+\cdots+x_n$`$\qquad x_1+\cdots+x_n$
- `$x_1=\cdots=x_n=0$`$\qquad x_1=\cdots=x_n=0$
- `$A_1\times\cdots\times A_n$`$\qquad A_1\times\cdots\times A_n$
- `$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$`$\qquad f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$
- `$x_1x_2\ldots x_n$`$\qquad x_1x_2\ldots x_n$
- `$(1-x)(1-x^2)\ldots(1-x^n)$`$\qquad (1-x)(1-x^2)\ldots(1-x^n)$
- `$n(n-1)\ldots(1)$`$\qquad n(n-1)\ldots(1)$

---

**More typography:** This is getting dangerously close to being more appropriate for TeX.SE, but here you have it: There's an important special case in which `\ldots` and `\cdots` don't give the correct spacing, namely when they appear at the very end of a formula, or when they appear just before a closing delimiter like `)'. In such situations an extra thin space is needed. For example, consider sentences like these:

- Prove that $(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+\cdots\,$.
- Clearly $a_i<b_i$ for $i=1$,$~2$, $\ldots\,$,$~n$.
- The coefficients $c_0$,$~c_1$, $\ldots$,$~c_n$ are positive.

To get the first sentence (I personally had to modify a couple of things above because they did not render as needed, but what follows is what Knuth describes in his book), the author typed

```
Prove that $(1-x)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+\cdots\,$.
```

Without the `\,` the period would have come too close to the `\cdots`. Similarly, the second sentence was typed thus:

```
Clearly $a_i<b_i$ for $i=1$,~2, $\ldots\,$,~$n$.
```

Notice the use of ties, which prevent bad line breaks. Here is an exercise from Knuth:

> **Exercise:** B. C. Dull tried to take a shortcut by typing the second example this way:

```
Clearly $a_i<b_i$ for~$i=1, 2, \ldots, n$.
```

> What's so bad about that?

Knuth's answer:

> **Explanation:** The commas belong to the sentence, not to the formula; his decision to put them into math mode meant that ${\rm\TeX}$ didn't put large enough spaces after them. Also, his formula `$i=1,2,\ldots,n$' allows no breaks between lines, except after the $=$, so he's risking overfull box problems. But suppose the sentence had been more terse: $$\text{Clearly $a_i<b_i\quad(i=1,2,\ldots,n)$.}$$ Then his idea would be basically correct:

```
Clearly $a_i<b_i$ \ ($i=1,2,\ldots,n$).
```

---

**My own thoughts:** I have noticed Knuth's great consistency in notational conventions. For example, in [TAOCP](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321751043), the seventh exercise in 1.2.11.2 reads as follows:

> What is the approximate value of $1^12^23^3\ldots n^n$?

It's very obvious Knuth means $\prod_{i=1}^n i^i$ here, just as your textbook has $\prod_{i=1}^nx_i$ to mean $x_1x_2\dots x_n$ as the notation they were introducing to represent multiplication.

I think *everyone* can agree that $x_1\cdot x_2\cdots x_n$ is absolutely hideous and should be avoided. Regardless, to a degree, I disagree with Brian M. Scott's comment about $x_1\cdot x_2\cdot\ldots\cdot x_n$ being the only "reasonable solution." For example, in David Gunderson's book *Handbook of Mathematical Induction*, one comes across the following exercise (screenshot to preserve authenticity):

[image]

Of course, that's not pretty at all. Having *five* center dots is a bit of overkill, and it looks rather horrible. In that case, I think the best solution is to do what Brian mentioned and have $1\cdot3\cdot5\cdot\ldots\cdot(2n-1)$ because you obviously can't have $135\ldots(2n-1)$, but Brian's predilection for using `\ldots` has been [stated before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095391/frac2n4n-n2-frac2n-12n-prod-k-1n-bigl1-frac1/1095409#comment2232269_1095409), where he often uses `\ldots` even between $+$ signs to get $+\ldots+$ (I don't think anything is *wrong* about this; there is bias in that comment though).

**What is *truly* important?** That people understand what you are communicating. Of course, it is nice to typeset things very well and make correct use of notation, but I don't think it's something to get too huffy and puffy about (although I do agree $x_1\cdot x_2\cdots x_n$ is a bit disappointing). As the amazing [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) points out (and egreg, if you are reading this, please correct me if I went amiss anywhere), the notation $f : A\to B$ is [not even correct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37789/using-colon-or-in-formulas/37791#37791)--it should be $f\colon A\to B$, but the former is *much* more common for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can write
$$x_1  x_2 \cdots  x_n = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i.$$

This does not work well for products whose first few terms
are literal numbers, however; in
$$1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 = \prod_{i=1}^4 (2i-1),$$
setting the numbers without any symbol for multiplication
would be simply incorrect in my opinion.

Among other alternatives already mentioned, I think I have sometimes
seen extra space inserted between the dot representing multiplication
and the dots representing ellipsis:

$$x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot \;\cdots\; \cdot x_n = \prod_{i=1}^n x_i.$$

This way you do not have something that just looks like five dots in a row.

In that vein,
$$1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \;\cdots\; \cdot (2n-1) = \prod_{i=1}^n (2i-1).$$